# Grouping, count of grouping variable, row total of another variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, cumulative-sum, summary

I want to plot a count of the program variable and also include total expenditure for each program.

```
projects <- read.table(text="
program               Expense
schools               15000
hospitals             180000
forest                30000
marine                200000
schools               7000
marine                29000
forest                4300
forest                1800
schools               1789",header=TRUE)
```

What I did:

```
projects |> 
group_by(program)|> 
summarise(count=n())|> 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(program,(-count),decreasing=T), y = count, fill= "grey")) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
        theme_clean()+
  coord_flip()
```

The above plot turned out fine.

But I also want to add the total expense for each program in the plot. so I added the following

```
projects |> 
group_by(program)|> 
summarise(count=n())|> 
ggplot(aes(x = reorder(program,(-count),decreasing=T), y = count, fill= "grey")) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
        theme_clean()+
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(aes(label = sum(`expense`)))
```

but r screamed backed at me

Comment: Can you provide the error message you received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran the `summarise` in your pipeline the `Expense` variable was dropped from the dataframe.  You should have included:

```
summarise(count=n(), expense=sum(Expense))|>
```

And then you could use:

```
geom_text(aes(label = expense))
```